# Adding swipe event to dynamically loaded content with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, events, swipe

Here is a js fiddle showing the problem.

http://jsfiddle.net/4CLqY/4/

The swipe works fine on the red box but not on the new blue box which is created after pressing the new button. (swipe across red box with mouse for change)

Sorry if this a dupe but I have not found any solution online which solves my particular issue.

The code is from the touchSwipe site

**javascript**

```
 $(function() {      
  //Enable swiping...
  $(".test").swipe( {
    //Generic swipe handler for all directions
    swipe:function(event, direction, distance, duration, fingerCount) {
      $(this).text("You swiped " + direction );  
    },
    //Default is 75px, set to 0 for demo so any distance triggers swipe
     threshold:0
  });
});

$(document).on('click','button',function(){


$('<div class="test" id="test2">Swipe me</div>').appendTo('body');

});
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="test">Swipe me</div>

<button>New</button>
```

Comment: When you start listening for swipes on `class="test"` you don't have the `id="test2"` element so the listener is not attached. But if you would attach the listener after you append it it should work. First you need to stop listening and than start a new listener. Or you could start a listener by targeting id.
please see this: http://jsfiddle.net/4CLqY/12/

Comment: @user2288766 thanks for the response, interesting how this works when attaching to a new selector but not if its re-added to the same test class which now has new members. I cant be adding unique IDs for all dynamic content.

Comment: you should just stop listener and then start it again. see this please: http://jsfiddle.net/4CLqY/19/

Comment: You shouldn't be adding dynamic content with an id, you will have duplicated ids.

Comment: @NicoSantangelo you are right, i just didn't change that part, to make a minimum changes. Your solution is obviously better. +1

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can reattach the swipe event to the new elements, because they don't exist when you add the initial event.

Try [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4CLqY/21/).

I added a  `addSwipeTo` function that takes a selector, and adds the event to the elements it matches.

Comment: noob question, how did you know you could destroy swipe() with swipe("destroy")? did you consult the docs or thats a common thing?

Comment: A bit of both, it's fairly common practice so I searched something like "destroy jquery touchSwipe" in google :)